# Autofill a form using curl and PHP

Tags: php, curl

The following PHP code works and it displays a form located on that page, my problem is how to Autofill the firstname textfield `ApplicantInfo1_FirstName` using PHP in that form ?

```
<?
   $handle=curl_init('https://www.progressivelp.com/onlineapplication/onlineapplication.aspx?sid=Metro2674957490&kid=1');
   curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
   curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   $content = curl_exec($handle);
   echo $content; // show target page
?>
```

Comment: I have a feeling that such a form is not intended for such "Autofilling"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty way using a regex:

```
$content = preg_replace(
  '/ApplicantInfo1_FirstName\"/i',
  'ApplicantInfo1_FirstName" value="My Name"',
  $content
);
```

- Find the input id
- Replace the id with the same but add the `value` attribute

**Edit:**

For the css part, it's almost the same:

```
$content = preg_replace(
  '/text\/css" href\=\"/i',
  'text/css" href="http://progressivelp.com/',
  $content
);
```

Comment: one more question if i want to replace the stylesheet from <link type="text/css" href="Styles/progressive.css" rel="Stylesheet" /><link type="text/css" href="Styles/datePicker.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> TO  <link type="text/css" href="https://www.progressivelp.com/Styles/progressive.css" rel="Stylesheet" /><link type="text/css" href="https://www.progressivelp.com/Styles/datePicker.css" rel="Stylesheet" />    how would i do that ?

Comment: I tried its not replacing the css you can check it here http://tinyurl.com/c698sy3

Comment: @user580950 little mistake since I just copy/paste the comment. I forgot the `http://`

Answer (score 0):

What about using `strpos()` to find the field in `$content`, then insert the `value="autofill"` part?

If you control the form, maybe you can pass a `$_GET` parameter to auto fill that field?

Finally, you could append some Javascript to `$content` for this purpose.